# Worklog feature in JIRA

Tags: software-development, estimation, jira

Do you have any suggestions when it comes to worklogs in JIRA?

Example:
Multiple people are working on the same issue. What would be the best way to track individual work log?

Comment: You may have an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you need this detail in work logging/tracking?

Answer (score 0):

Like Thomas, I'm curious what you want this data for.. but, since the question is tagged with "estimation", I'll observe the following:

- If the goal is to get a feel for what each person is doing, I'd assume that shared tickets are the exception rather than the rule, and just ignore them.

  - If they're *not* the exception, I might use subtasks for each person, but subtasks don't always play nicely with the rest of Jira. The "Work Log" tab down by the comments does show who logged what, though; you could presumably do something with that, maybe with help from your Jira Admins.
- If the goal is to help people improve their estimates, then I'd ensure that for tickets that multiple people will work on, the estimate includes the effort of everyone who will do the work, regardless who makes the estimate.

Answer (score -1):

Every Jira issue can be assigned to a single person. That's for a reason; when you assign a task to multiple people, it means that it is assigned to no one. To hold someone accountable, you have to assign a task to a single person and expect the task to be completed by a single person.

In that sense, multiple people should not work on the same issue. If they are, it means that the issue is not granular enough to track. You have to focus on defining the work granular enough to be assignable to a single person (for example it can be a task or a subtask in Jira). After this effort, it will be easier to track the work log.